# PyQt5 and QAbstractListModel::columnCount

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qabstractlistmodel

QTreeView ignores columnCount() of class inherited from QAbstractListModel and shows only first column:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView

class Model(QAbstractListModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        return None

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 0

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = Model()
list_view = QTreeView()
list_view.setModel(model)
list_view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Relevant C++ code works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A **list** only has one column.

Comment: QAbstractItemModel (base class for all models) has default implementation of columnCount() that returns 0. I can provide my own implementation, and it works in C++, but not in Python. I consider my model as list model because it has list of objects without childs (i.e. structure is not hierarchical), and columns display objects properties. Is using QAbstractListModel for it is a bad practice? I've seen it in multiple projects (e.g. qBittorrent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt docs:

> The [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html)
>   class provides an abstract model that can be subclassed to create
>   **one-dimensional** list models. [emphasis added]

But you clearly want a **two-dimensional** model, so use [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) instead.

Comment: Maybe QAbstractTableModel is more suitable for non-hierarchical structure? I replaced QAbstractListModel by QAbstractTableModel  in test code and it worked. Somehow i thought that I can't use QAbstractTableModel with QTreeView.

Comment: What have you got against `QAbstractItemModel`? It works perfectly fine with tree-views. A `QAbstractTableModel` is not required for a simple 2D list.

Comment: As far as i inderstood from documentation and Qt source code:

To use QAbstractItemModel you should implement index(), parent(), rowCount(), columnCount() and data(). First two is already done in QAbstractListModel and QAbstractTableModel.
QAbstractListModel is one-dimensional non-hierarchical model.
QAbstractTableModel is two-dimensional non-hierachical model.
QAbstractItemModel can be one or two dimensional and can be hierachical.
All of them can be shown in QTreeView, but QTableView is only for non-hierachical models, and QListView for non-hierachical and one-dimensional.

Comment: If you knew all of that, what was the point of your question?

Comment: I learned this just now after you gave me clue to solve issue :). Just want to know if I missed anything.

Comment: Maybe you could consider using [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html). I very rarely go to all the trouble of writing custom item model subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this class.